# How do I check for and remove quotes in Shell/Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I get some data in SHA 256 but sometimes the data have quotations around it. How do I check for quotations and remove if quotes are present?

expected input:

```
C968F28F6CE18487CB327D7C9ACFDA04F02F76DD17D3982F6275508CB2D1803A
```

Need to be fixed (either remove quotes or trim the spaces):

```
"C968F28F6CE18487CB327D7C9ACFDA04F02F76DD17D3982F6275508CB2D1803A"
"   C968F28F6CE18487CB327D7C9ACFDA04F02F76DD17D3982F6275508CB2D1803A"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with all the necessary details for someone else to see the problem themselves (and observe what you already tried). Without a concrete example, we don't know enough about your data format to intuit potentially-pertinent details. (Some examples of questions a good example in the question will moot: What specific *kind* of quoting? Might it be necessary to perform shell-like word-splitting? Is this caused by content meant to be parsed as shell syntax being treated as literal data instead?)

Comment: ...if this is specifically the quoting format created by `sha256sum`, for example, that's a very pertinent detail (and if that *is* the case, is there a reason you aren't letting `sha256sum` itself recover the original filenames and check the sums, as it will do when called with `--check`?)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, it's hard to say, but here's a `tr` command that naively removes quotes:

```
tr -d \"\'
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", including the bullet point about questions which "are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The reasoning given is to save me headache, and where this answer only took me a minute to slap together, I'm not concerned :) But I'm also inferring you don't think bad questions deserve an answer, which is valid.

Comment: It's less about vague questions being undeserving and more about answers' correctness being impossible to judge when the questions are inadequately clarified. If we're giving bad advice (and in shell, bad advice can often result in exploitable vulnerabilities) because we don't understand the use to which our answers will be put, that's an unfortunate place to be.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, for other people voting on it, gotcha

Comment: Exactly. In this case, the OP has clarified this question enough that we can be reasonably confident that this answer is safe (f/e, we now know they aren't trying to parse quote-surrounded filenames *next to* the sums, as created by some common checksum-list-maintenance tools), but that wasn't the case earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You may use sed command to remove the quotes. This is some example:

```
sed -i -e 's/"//g' file
```

Reference also from [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159367/using-sed-to-find-and-replace)

Or, maybe easier, is to use vim's command to do it.

```
:%s/"//g
```